# Blue Prism Utility File-Management Object missing

Tags: file-management, blueprism, utility

After importing the "Process Examples - Files", found here 
https://portal.blueprism.com/products/developer-jumpstart,
in to my Blue Prism instance, if I open it, Blue Prism states, "This process contains references to some processes or business objects that are not available."
 
In fact, the  Object "**Utility - File Management**", referenced in page "Move File", is missing.
May somebody provide a link or hint, how to obtain the Utility - File Management object to import it in my Blue Prism instance?
PS: Please, apologize me, if the answer seems obvious for you: I am a Blue Prism beginner (just got the consolidation exercise done), looking for that object and I can't find it. 
Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha! 
The following directory (default installation path) 
C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\VBO 
contains a lot of interesting objects. The files are: 
BPA Object*.XML
There lies in particular the one I am looking for. 
(Use menu File / Import or Ctr+I to import in to Blue Prism)